# Build rocksdb static library inside R package

Tags: r, makefile, rcpp, rocksdb

I tried to use the rocksdb inside R package. I used the following `src/Makevars`:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11

PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I./rocksdb/include/
PKG_LIBS = rocksdb/librocksdb.a -lbz2 -lz -lzstd -llz4 -lsnappy

$(SHLIB): rocksdb/librocksdb.a

rocksdb/librocksdb.a: rocksdb/Makefile
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)" LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)" \
       $(MAKE) -d --jobs=3 --directory=rocksdb static_lib

clean:
    $(MAKE) --directory=rocksdb clean
```

Package installation failed with many errors (see build log below).

You could reproduce this case using Docker container:

Necessary commands:

```sh
docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-ver:latest bash
```

Execute in container:

```sh
apt-get update
# install system deps
apt-get install -y libgflags-dev libsnappy-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblz4-dev libzstd-dev
apt-get install -y git-core
# install R deps
install2.r Rcpp checkmate R6 tinytest
cd /tmp
git clone https://gitlab.com/artemklevtsov/rocksdb
cd rocksdb/
git submodule init
git submodule update
R CMD INSTALL .
```

But I can successfully run `make` directly in the rocksdb source directory:

```sh
cd src/rocksdb/
make static_lib
```

How can I fix `src/Makevars` to build `rocksdb` during R package installation?

Links:

- [build log](https://privatebin.net/?d494870bdae5c5d5#FQSVXRhLFPLwucoY548BDURgHv4Yr2qwP8sCz19NjiNn)
- [rocksdb install guide](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md)
- [R package source repo](https://gitlab.com/artemklevtsov/rocksdb/tree/master)

Comment: I won't have time to play with this in detail but the broad strokes look correct.  What a few packages to is to farm out the _creation_ of the required static library to the `configure` script and then just depend on it.  Other package sometimes just invoke a help script from the `src/Makevars` too.  It really is more about R build system wrangling at this point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem we should reset `MAKEFLAGS` variable. So the right way to do it:

```
rocksdb/librocksdb.a: rocksdb/Makefile
    CFLAGS="$(CCFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)" MAKEFLAGS="" \
       $(MAKE) -C rocksdb DISABLE_WARNING_AS_ERROR=1 static_lib
```

`MAKEFLAGS` content:

```sh
MAKEFLAGS= -- OBJECTS=RcppExports.o\ backup.o\ checkpoint.o\ db.o\ del.o\ exists.o\ get.o\ keys.o\ list.o\ options.o\ property.o\ put.o\ size.o\ sst.o\ utils.o\ version.o\ wrap.o SHLIB=rocksdb.so SHLIB_LD=$$(SHLIB_CXX11LD) SHLIB_LDFLAGS=$$(SHLIB_CXX11LDFLAGS) CXXPICFLAGS=$$(CXX11PICFLAGS) CXXFLAGS=$$(CXX11FLAGS) CXX=$$(CXX11)\ $$(CXX11STD)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer but an observation (for now):

I tried to reproduce this in a docker container. The R package build failed, but also the plain build when using the same flags as used by R, but without parallel jobs and `make`'s debug output:

```
root@e8749c4bca63:/tmp/rocksdb/src# CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -fpic" AR="ar" RANLIB="ranlib" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" \
>    make --directory=rocksdb static_lib
[...]
  CC       util/bloom.o
  CC       util/build_version.o
util/build_version.cc:5:42: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 const char* rocksdb_build_compile_date = __DATE__;
                                          ^~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2029: recipe for target 'util/build_version.o' failed
make: *** [util/build_version.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/rocksdb/src/rocksdb'
```

So it looks as if `-Wdate-time` got promoted to `-Werror=date-time`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think we can omit all R flags except `-fpic`.

Comment: This flags defined in the `/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf`.

Comment: Also `-Werror` flag added in the `src/rosckdb/Makefile` (lines 350-352).

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov ACK, and without the flag rocksdb builds fine outside of the R package, but there are still errors when build from `Makevars`. I would go for building the library in a `configure` script (maybe after checking that it is not already installed) as hinted by Dirk. See the `nloptr` package for an example.